# Class method building

Tags: c#

I did this kind of class in the past and I can't remember exactly how..

Say you have this class :

```
public class TestMethod
{
    private string a, b, c, d, e;

    public void SetA(string text) => a = text;
    public void SetB(string text) => b = text;
    public void SetC(string text) => c = text;
    public void SetD(string text) => d = text;
    public void SetE(string text) => e = text;

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("A: {0}\nB: {1}\nC: {2}\nD: {3}\nE: {4}\n", a,b,c,d,e));
    }
}
```

And you would like to call it like so:

```
TestMethod method = new TestMethod();
method.SetA("").SetB("").Print();
```

What do I need to add to my class and what is this called ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called a call-chain. You have to add a `return this` statement.

```
public class TestMethod
{
    private string a, b, c, d, e;

    public TestMethod SetA(string text) { a = text; return this; }
    public TestMethod SetB(string text) { b = text; return this; }
    public TestMethod SetC(string text) { c = text; return this; }
    public TestMethod SetD(string text) { d = text; return this; }
    public TestMethod SetE(string text) { e = text; return this; }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("A: {0}\nB: {1}\nC: {2}\nD: {3}\nE: {4}\n", a,b,c,d,e));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sadistik You could accept it as the correct answer :)

Comment: as mentioned above your comment i was waiting for the timer.. there is a 15 mins wait before you can accept an answer after posting. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sadistik Didn't see it, sorry. Thanks!